# Open cmd.exe in excel 365 vba

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I want to open cmd.exe in excel 365 vba.
I used to open shell in excel 2013 but it seems not to work in excel 365.

I tried this code and works for calc.exe, ... but not for cmd.exe.
Does it need a special parameter/permission to run from vba.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr

Sub ShellExec()
Dim strFile As String
Dim strAction As String
Dim lngErr As LongPtr

' Edit this:
strFile = "notepad.exe"  ' the file you want to open/etc.
strAction = "OPEN"  ' action might be OPEN, NEW or other, depending on what you need to do

lngErr = ShellExecute(0, strAction, strFile, "", "", 0)

' optionally, add code to test lngErr

End Sub
```

Kind regards,
w.

Comment: Try `Shell "cmd.exe", vbNormalFocus`. But if you like more `ShellExecute`, try it in this way: `ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, "cmd.exe", vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus`. But **do you only need to open the commander window**?

Comment: thx for the shell. Indeed cmd needs to execute a program.

Comment: Is it a top secret executable? Should we ask about it? Do you know what command line to write/use? Do you need running it **As Administrator**?  It will be good to edit your question and better describe what you try accomplishing, I think...

Comment: It's not topsecret but colleague it's not available for extra info.

Comment: OK, if you know how to configure it to run the command you need, I do not have any problem with that. But I cannot understand what such an application to be, since you cannot show its name... Nobody here is interested in knowing what applications you use, I only tried helping with a code able to deal in case of your real need. I wish you a good day!

Answer (score 0):

use SW_SHOW = 5 as last parameter

```
Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr

Sub ShellExec()
Dim strFile As String
Dim strAction As String
Dim lngErr As LongPtr

' Edit this:
strFile = "cmd.exe"  ' the file you want to open/etc.
strAction = "OPEN"  ' action might be OPEN, NEW or other, depending on what you need to do

lngErr = ShellExecute(0, strAction, strFile, "", "", 5)

' optionally, add code to test lngErr

End Sub
```